# Is there a way to remove the Firefox icon from the Mate panel without the GUI?

Tags: mate-desktop

Is there a way to remove the Firefox icon from the Mate panel without a GUI (using the command line)?

[image]

I'm using Fedora 22 and Mate 1.10.x

Comment: "without GUI" ?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to remove it programmatically without the use of a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

i can tell you this settings of additional launchers are stored in the dconf-editor under *org* -> *mate* -> *panel* -> *objects* -> *object_**X***...
 you should additionally (or maybe it is enough if you only) delete the corresponding object in the arrangement under *org* -> *mate* -> *panel* -> *general* -> *object-id-list*.

now you need the correct way to edit the [deconf-settings](http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/docs:gsettings) via terminal!
(maybe i'll update this answer in future...) but have a look at `gsettings --help` and/or `man gsettings`!